# Написать программу, которая определяет кол-во чисел в данном промежутке, единичный разряд которых равен 9

Tags: python

Промежуток - [10;1000). Нужно для олимпиады, не знаю, как посчитать все числа, оканчивающиеся на 9

Comment: а что именно не получилось? Приведите код с вашей попыткой (кнопка "править")

Comment: Я не знаю как посчитать все числа, оканчивающиеся на 9. Пайтон начал изучать в этом году. Вопрос из школьной олимпиады.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = [i for i in range(10,1000+1) if str(i)[-1]=='9']
count = len(result)
```

Comment: Прям кодгольф))

Comment: len() ещё от этого взять - надо количество же :)

Comment: Извините, а вы не могли бы объяснить эту строку и всё что в ней происходит? Я был бы вам очень признателен. Просто код я написал, но всё еще ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @Михаил мы перебираем `i` от 10 до 1000, проверяем каждый раз равна ли последняя ее цифра `9` и если да, то она добавляется.

Answer (score 1):

в вашем диапазоне можно просто завести цикл от 19 до 999 включительно и считать кол-во итераций с шагом 10:

```
count = 0
for i in range(19, 1000, 10):
    count += 1

print(count)   #  99
```

ну или `print(len([i for i in range(19, 1000, 10)]))`

Или самый простой способ, это взять первое с конца вашего диапазона число, оканчивающееся на 9, и целочисленно разделить на 10

```
print(999 // 10)  #  99
```

Comment: А для чего здесь используются квадратные скобки? Я понимаю, что ими обозначают массив, но что они делают в этой ситуации? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Михаил в данном случае это генератор списков, на выходе будет список из всех значений, подходящих под наши требования, а с помощью `len` считаем кол-во элементов в нем

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще и за константное время:

```
print((999-19) // 10 + 1)
```